# Proxy routing in Nuxt.js

Tags: typescript, proxy, nuxt.js

Please, help me! I use the [Nuxt.js framework](https://ru.nuxtjs.org/) and I have this config in **nuxt.config.ts**:

```
... // some code here
,
axios: {
  proxy: true
},
proxy: {
  "/api": {
    target: "https://example.com" // this is a fictional address
  }
}
```

Then, when I try to fetch some JSON data (at local server), e.g.:

```
this.axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/my-json');
```

I have this problem:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/api/my-json/'
>   (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/api/my-json') from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

But when I add slash character ("`/`") at the end of the address, e.g.:

```
this.axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/my-json/');
```

I have not a problem! Why?